# R function that works on previous observation

Tags: r

I have a collection of user's IP addresses and the associated time they hit a particular website.  I am trying to get the change in time between each IP address change.  To make this easier, I've assigned each row a label as to whether or not it represents a change from the previous row, and I've done this on a per-user basis.

sample data:

```
user.nm ip.addr.txt login.sessn.ts  change.label    
b   c   2/18/2013 16:08 FALSE   
b   c   2/18/2013 16:08 FALSE   
b   c   2/28/2013 13:37 FALSE   
b   c   2/28/2013 16:10 FALSE   
b   c   2/28/2013 16:20 FALSE   
b   c   3/5/2013 9:29   FALSE   
b   c   3/6/2013 11:42  FALSE   
b   c   3/11/2013 13:55 FALSE   <-
b   b   6/25/2013 13:22 TRUE    <-
b   d   6/25/2013 13:22 FALSE   <-
b   b   8/12/2013 13:18 TRUE    <-
b   c   8/12/2013 13:18 FALSE   
b   c   8/20/2013 15:13 FALSE   
b   c   8/20/2013 15:13 FALSE   
b   c   9/23/2013 14:08 FALSE   
b   c   9/23/2013 14:09 FALSE   
b   c   9/25/2013 11:00 FALSE   
b   c   10/18/2013 16:54    FALSE   
b   c   10/18/2013 16:54    FALSE   
b   c   10/30/2013 14:33    FALSE   
b   c   11/8/2013 15:03 FALSE   
b   c   11/18/2013 11:30    FALSE   
b   c   11/18/2013 11:33    FALSE   
b   c   11/20/2013 16:08    FALSE   
b   c   11/21/2013 11:51    FALSE   
b   c   11/21/2013 11:52    FALSE   
b   c   11/21/2013 15:18    FALSE   
b   c   11/21/2013 16:40    FALSE   
b   c   11/21/2013 16:44    FALSE   
b   c   11/21/2013 16:45    FALSE   
b   c   11/21/2013 16:45    FALSE   
b   c   11/29/2013 15:41    FALSE   
b   c   11/29/2013 15:41    FALSE   
a   a   1/9/2013 15:32  FALSE   
a   a   1/9/2013 15:32  FALSE   
a   a   1/9/2013 15:32  FALSE   
a   a   1/9/2013 15:32  FALSE   
a   a   1/10/2013 10:39 FALSE   
a   a   1/10/2013 10:39 FALSE   
a   a   1/10/2013 10:39 FALSE   
a   a   1/11/2013 10:31 FALSE   
a   a   1/11/2013 10:31 FALSE   
a   a   1/18/2013 12:30 FALSE   
a   a   2/22/2013 10:54 FALSE   <-
a   b   3/6/2013 12:27  TRUE    <-
```

dput:

```
sample.data=structure(list(user.nm = c("b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"), 
    ip.addr.txt = c("c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "b", 
    "c", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
    "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
    "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b"
    ), login.sessn.ts = structure(c(1361221680, 1361221680, 1362076620, 
    1362085800, 1362086400, 1362493740, 1362588120, 1363024500, 
    1372180920, 1372180920, 1376327880, 1376327880, 1377025980, 
    1377025980, 1379959680, 1379959740, 1380121200, 1382129640, 
    1382129640, 1383157980, 1383940980, 1384792200, 1384792380, 
    1384981680, 1385052660, 1385052720, 1385065080, 1385070000, 
    1385070240, 1385070300, 1385070300, 1385757660, 1385757660, 
    1357763520, 1357763520, 1357763520, 1357763520, 1357832340, 
    1357832340, 1357832340, 1357918260, 1357918260, 1358530200, 
    1361548440, 1362590820), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    change.label = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)), .Names = c("user.nm", "ip.addr.txt", 
"login.sessn.ts", "change.label"), row.names = c(NA, -45L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am attempting to write a ddply summarize statement to give me the difference in time between each IP change per user (among other things).  Normally, I would just subset the DF by all observations that have the label TRUE and use this as my ddply dataframe.  however, I need the difference between the pairs of rows where FALSE is immediately followed by a TRUE.

ideally, the output dataframe would look like this:

```
user.nm change count    min.change.tme  max.change.time
a   2   10 sec  4 hours
b   1   1 hour  1 hour
```

I was hoping to use some kind of index lookup function like `match,` but I'm not sure how to translate this into a function.

is there some kind of "look-behind" function in R that could help with this?

my code so for getting the number of IP changes works well so far, and is below:

```
did.change<-function(vec){
  #consumes vector
  #returns a p-1  boolean vector of instances where element is not directly repeated (duplicated)
  b.vec=head(vec, -1)==tail(vec, -1)
  return(!b.vec)
}
###this function works on the ENTIRE list of entries per user, which is to broad
time.changes<-function(vec){
  a=head(vec-1)-tail(vec,-1)
  return(abs(a))
}


user.changes=ddply(sample.data, c("user.nm"), summarize, 
                   change.count=sum(did.change(ip.addr.txt)))
                  #max.change.time=max(time.changes(login.sessn.ts)),
                  #min.change.time=min(time.changes(login.sessn.ts)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes, and it is called `diff`!

long answer:

```
is_diff <- which(diff(sample.data$change.label)==1)

ss <- do.call(c,lapply(is_diff,function(x) c(x,x+1)))

sample.data[ss,]
user.nm ip.addr.txt      login.sessn.ts change.label
8        b           c 2013-03-11 10:55:00        FALSE
9        b           b 2013-06-25 10:22:00         TRUE
10       b           c 2013-06-25 10:22:00        FALSE
11       b           b 2013-08-12 10:18:00         TRUE
44       a           a 2013-02-22 07:54:00        FALSE
45       a           b 2013-03-06 09:27:00         TRUE
```

Here is one way to calculate the changes in login times:

```
ss_list <- lapply(is_diff,function(x) c(x,x+1))
logins <- lapply(ss_list,function(x) sample.data[x,"login.sessn.ts"])

library(lubridate)
lapply(logins,function(x) diff(ymd_hms(x)))
```

If you want to break that down my `user.nm`, try using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr) 

sample.data %>%
  mutate(rownum = 1:nrow(sample.data)) %>%
  filter(rownum %in% ss) %>%
  group_by(user.nm) %>%
  mutate(change = login.sessn.ts - lag(login.sessn.ts))

  user.nm ip.addr.txt      login.sessn.ts change.label rownum            change
1       b           c 2013-03-11 10:55:00        FALSE      8           NA days
2       b           b 2013-06-25 10:22:00         TRUE      9 9.156420e+06 days
3       b           c 2013-06-25 10:22:00        FALSE     10 0.000000e+00 days
4       b           b 2013-08-12 10:18:00         TRUE     11 4.146960e+06 days
5       a           a 2013-02-22 07:54:00        FALSE     44           NA days
6       a           b 2013-03-06 09:27:00         TRUE     45 1.206458e+01 days
```

Comment: thank you for this, I think I'll need to look into how diff works a bit more.  In your code, what is the `c` referring to in `ss <- do.call(c,lapply(is_diff,function(x) c(x,x+1)))`?

Comment: c binds objects into a vector.  I used it twice: once to attach a row number to the next row number (`c(x,x+1)`) and then to attach all the results together into a single vector (`do.call(c,...)`)

Comment: I was hoping to get a vector of lagged differences for each user.nm, is there a way to modify this solution so that is possible?

Comment: edited!  If you want to do something by groups, `dplyr` functions are an excellent tool

Comment: Note that `diff` and `lag` are very similar.  the difference (ha) is that the former returns n-1 elements for a vector of length n, while the latter will give you NA for the first value in each group.